# PyXB reading and writing XMLdoc

Tags: xml, pyxb

I am using `PyXB` to read and write `XML` files.
When I try to use `CreateFromDocument` method to read `XML` files and create classes. I am getting following error. -

> No handlers could be found for logger "pyxb.binding.content"

Comment: I suspect there is additional failure information you are not sharing here or is this message all of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a issue in the Python library. The PyXB libraries was written to use the logging module however it has not been configured and so it throws the error. Try adding the following to your file:

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig()
```